# using renderRichText - receiving an error Node is not defined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am having an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when I tried to use **documentToReactComponents** to output the body of contentful post. If I comment it out, and try to console log, it displays documents etc.
Having edited the code to the suggested answer, I am receiving another error "Node is not defined" using **renderRichText**

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import {  graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Head from '../components/head'
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"

export const query = graphql`
    query($slug: String!) {
        contentfulBlogPost(
                slug:  {
                    eq: $slug
                }
            ) {
                title
                slug
                publishedDate(formatString: "MMM Do, YYYY")
                body {
                   raw
                }
            }
    }
`
const Blog = (props) => {
    const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
    const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>

    const options = {
        renderMark: {
            [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
          },
        renderNode: {
            [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
            [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
                const alt= node.data.target.fields.title['en-US']
                const url= node.data.target.fields.file['en-US'].url
              return (
                <>
                  <img src={url} alt={alt} />
                
                </>
              )
            },
            [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: node => {
                return (
                    <Layout>
                         <Head home_title="Blog Post" />
                          <h1>{props.data.contentfulBlogPost.title}</h1>
                          <p>{props.data.contentfulBlogPost.publishedDate}</p>
                          {props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body}
              
                    </Layout>
                  )
            },
        },
    }
  renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
}

export default Blog
```

I have tried to read through from [Github](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-react-renderer) but still receiving the same error. I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add **references** to the graphql query, unlike with json, the body has **raw** and **references**. With that being said, you need to append this to the body after the raw;

```
references{
           contentful_id
           title
           fixed{
               src
                }
          }
```

Then you can you id to search for the title and src as you can see above.

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import {  graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Head from '../components/head'
import { documentToReactComponents } from '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer'
import { BLOCKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
export const query = graphql`
    query($slug: String!){
        post: contentfulBlogPost(slug:{eq:$slug}){
            title
            publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
            body{
                raw
                references{
                    contentful_id
                    title
                    fixed{
                        src
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`

const Blog = (props) => {
    const assets = new Map(props.data.post.body.references.map(ref => [ref.contentful_id,ref]))
    const options = {
        renderNode:{
            [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
                const url = assets.get(node.data.target.sys.id).fixed.src
                const alt = assets.get(node.data.target.sys.id).title
                return <img alt={alt} src={url}/>
            }
        }
    }
    
    return(
        <Layout>
            
            <h1>{props.data.post.title}</h1>
            <p>{props.data.post.publishedDate}</p>
            {documentToReactComponents(JSON.parse(props.data.post.body.raw),options)}
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Blog
```

Comment: why do i don't find references

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the following approach:

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
​
const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
​
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
  },
}
​
renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
```

*Note: extracted from [Contentful docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/)*

Using `renderRichText` built-in method (from `gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text`). Your code seems a little bit deprecated or at least, some methods.

The following code will never work:

```
"embedded-asset-block" : (node) => {
    const alt= node.data.target.fields.title['en-US']
    const url= node.data.target.fields.file['en-US'].url
    return <imag src={url} alt={alt} />
}
```

You need to use the providers of the dependency (`@contentful/rich-text-types`), that are `BLOCKS` and `MARKS`. You can always access to the dependency to check the methods, however, `embedded-asset-block` stands for `BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET` or `BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY`, so:

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
​
const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
​
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
     // manipulate here your embedded asset
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: node => {
     // manipulate here your embedded entry
      return (
        <>
        <div>I'm an embedded entry</div>      
        </>
      )
    },
  },
}
​
renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
```

Comment: I received this  Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

Comment: Clean your cache and try it again

Comment: I have done that but the same error, let me edit the question and paste my updated code for you to see

Comment: `embedded-asset-block` this will never work... I' will update the answer

Comment: I have edited the question, I am receiving node not defined

Comment: Have you checked both `BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET` and `BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY`? Is your image published?

Comment: I don't even know how to check the two aforementioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228190/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-game-zone).